# which version of jakartacommons-codec does jakartacommons-io 2.1 use?

Tags: java, apache

In which version of JakartaCommons-IO is JakartaCommons-codec 1.5 and above available ?

Facing error in JakartaCommons-codec 1.4

Answer (score 1):

First of all the Jakarta project was officially retired in 2011.  The process started in 2005.  When the Apache foundation started promoting Jakarta subprojects to full top-level projects.  So, for example, if you look for recent Maven artifacts with "jakarta" in the name, you won't find much.

Reference: http://jakarta.apache.org/

To answer your question:

1. The Official site for Apache Commons-IO is here: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/
2. The Official site for Apache Commons-Codec is here: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/
3. I spent 20 minutes or so looking at the POM files, and from what I can tell, there are no overt dependencies of Commons-Codec on Commons-IO or vice versa.

If you have Maven dependency issues, they are most likely due to other libraries depending on specific versions of commons-io or commons-codec.

But if you just have a problem with runtime errors due to bugs in some version of commons-codec, you should be able to change the version of that library with worrying about the commons-io version.

---

If you are talking about RPM or DEB or similar packages (via Linux distros), you should observe that the name "jakarta" stopped appearing in the package names a long time ago.  And you probably shouldn't be relying on the package manager for Java application library dependencies anyway ...